# Segmentation fault in Hackerrank

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

While practising some problems on hackerrank  I encountered this problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/permutations-of-strings/problem).

The Code is giving correct output on my PC but a segmentation fault on hackerrank. Please let me know where I am going wrong??

Also, let me know how can I rectify my mistakes and if there's a better or effective solution for this problem.

The link for the hackerrank problem is given above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void swap(char **str1_ptr, char **str2_ptr)
{
    char *temp = *str1_ptr;
    *str1_ptr = *str2_ptr;
    *str2_ptr = temp;
}

void reverse(int index, char **s, int n)
{
    int x = n - 1;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i+=2)
    {
        swap(&s[i], &s[x]);
        x--;
    }
}

int next_permutation(int n, char **s)
{
    /**
    * Complete this method
    * Return 0 when there is no next permutation and 1 otherwise
    * Modify array s to its next permutation
    */

    int k, l, flag = 0;
    char *temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0)
        {
            k = i;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s[k], s[i]) < 0)
        {
            l = i;
        }
    }

    swap(&s[k], &s[l]);
    // temp = s[k];
    // s[k] = s[l];
    // s[l] = temp;

    reverse(k + 1, s, n);

    if (flag)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **s;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    s = calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        s[i] = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s%c", s[i], i == n - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
    } while (next_permutation(n, s));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(s[i]);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any python nor C++ code, why did you tag them?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong tags. I am new to programming and this is my first question on StackOverflow.I thought it is mandatory to use at least 5 tags in question that's why I used 2 extra tags. I will never repeat this mistake in future.

Comment: All information necessary for understanding a question should be in the question itself. Links to external web sites are okay for supplemental information but are not substitutes for fully stating the problem in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will take care of this thing next time. Sorry for improper question framing as this was my first question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `next_permutation`, `k` is never given a value if the strings are in descending order. `l` may also never be given a value.

Comment: But in that hackerrank problem, it is mentioned that the input array will be sorted always. Also, I am not able to figure out where that segmentation fault is coming from.

Comment: @NishantBharwani: The initial order of the array is irrelevant. Your program changes the order, so eventually `next_permutation` is called with the array in descending order. Then your code has a bug because it never assigns values to `k` and `l`. Fix it.

Comment: Thank You for help and making my first question on StackOverflow a success